# How to make an iterator over several sorted lists?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Ok, so this is an interview question that I got, and only performed mediocre on at the time. I am wondering what the optimal solution is and how it is best implemented.

You are given multiple sorted lists, construct *something* that allows us to iterate over all these lists from the smallest to the largest element.

Example:

```
{ -2, 5, 10}
{ 2, 9, 11}
{ -5, 9}


-> -5, -2, 2, 5, 9, 9, 10, 11
```

**Update:**

With a bit of help from the SO chat #c-questions-and-answers and @Nican in particular, I've gotten this ship to fly somehow. I have posted my working code as an answer to allow for other solutions as well.

The answer I have posted below is still messy, and in particular I have not implemented == and != correctly. I still need help on those.

**Justification for this question**

Finding clean and minimalistic custom iterator implementations online is not that common. And I believe this question may serve as a good starting point for others to enhance their understanding of iterators and best practices.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by *"Implement end() to check which of the underlying ends are the biggest."* I can't see how that will help you. Just have `end()` return an iterator object with an identifier that tells you you're at the end of the sequence. Then make sure your `==` operator handles it. For a forward iterator write `++`, assignment operator, etc. Then refactor to make a `const_iterator` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not a complete answer**

I've implemented a partly solution to the point that it works. This is not a complete, nor correct implementation in lines with the requirements of a input_iterator. This illustrates the point, and the remaining legwork is up to whoever feels the call.

--

I just picked this up again from my notes and efforts yesterday. I've gotten some really nice help from Nican.

I'm using a heap to keep the lists inside my structure. (Which has the valid critique that I am reinventing the priority_queue). There are several things still missing here, among other things:

- Copy constructor
- Post-fix ++ operator
- Proper == and != implementation, I'm only comparing size.
- This could easily be a forward_iterator.

I got to the point where I've built my understanding of iterators. And this is as far as I'm going to take it this time around.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iter>
struct SortedListIterItem {
  Iter it_beg;
  Iter it_end;
  /* Used by the heap to sort ascending */
  bool operator<(const SortedListIterItem<Iter>& other) {
    return *it_beg > *other.it_beg;
  }
  bool operator==(const SortedListIterItem<Iter>& other) {
    return it_beg == other.it_begin && it_end == *other.it_beg;
  }
  SortedListIterItem<Iter>(Iter _begin, Iter _end)
      : it_beg(_begin), it_end(_end){};
};

template <typename Iter>
class SortedListsIter {
  // member typedefs provided through inheriting from std::iterator
  class iterator {
    std::vector<SortedListIterItem<Iter> > m_items;

   public:
    iterator(std::vector<SortedListIterItem<Iter> > _items = {})
        : m_items(_items){};
    iterator& operator++() {
      std::pop_heap(m_items.begin(), m_items.end());
      SortedListIterItem<Iter>& largest = m_items.back();

      if (++largest.it_beg == largest.it_end) {
        m_items.pop_back();
      } else {
        std::push_heap(m_items.begin(), m_items.end());
      }
      return *this;
    }
    // iterator traits
    using value_type = typename Iter::value_type;
    using pointer = typename Iter::pointer;
    using reference = typename Iter::reference;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    /** A simplified comparator, which is not a correct implementation.
     *  While it does work for regular for loops. */
    bool operator!=(iterator other) { 
      return (m_items.size() != other.m_items.size());
    }
    value_type operator*() const { 
      return *(m_items.front().it_beg); 
    };
  };
  std::vector<SortedListIterItem<Iter> > m_items;

 public:
  void add_list(Iter it_begin, Iter it_end) {
    if (it_begin != it_end) {
      m_items.push_back(SortedListIterItem<Iter>(it_begin, it_end));
      std::push_heap(m_items.begin(), m_items.end());
    }
    // Ignore empty lists.
  }
  iterator begin() { return iterator(m_items); };
  iterator end() {
    std::vector<SortedListIterItem<Iter> > _items;
    return iterator(_items);
  };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::forward_list<std::string> animals = {"Cat", "Dog", "Horse"};
  std::forward_list<std::string> fish = {"Dolphin", "Mermaid", "Shark"};
  std::forward_list<std::string> birds = {"Crow", "Duck", "Eagle"};
  SortedListsIter<std::forward_list<std::string>::iterator> my_string_iter;
  my_string_iter.add_list(fish.begin(), fish.end());
  my_string_iter.add_list(animals.begin(), animals.end());
  my_string_iter.add_list(birds.begin(), birds.end());

  for (auto i : my_string_iter) {
    std::cout << " " << i << ",";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  for (auto i : my_string_iter) {
    std::cout << " " << i << ",";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::vector<int> l4 = {1, 2, 99};
  std::vector<int> l5 = {-11, -4, 3};
  std::vector<int> l6 = {-5, 1};

  SortedListsIter<std::vector<int>::iterator> my_iter2;
  my_iter2.add_list(l4.begin(), l4.end());
  my_iter2.add_list(l5.begin(), l5.end());
  my_iter2.add_list(l6.begin(), l6.end());

  for (auto i : my_iter2) {
    std::cout << " " << i << ",";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `SortedListsIter::iterator` should contain a copy of all the items, rather than reference, so that you can be `ForwardIterator` instead of `InputIterator`. You also avoid the dangling reference in the end iterator (which can be a default constructed iterator, as `iterator::iterator(std::vector<SortedListIterItem<Iter> > _items = {}) : m_items(_items){};`)

Two heaps may differ in order of elements, so we use `std::is_permutation` to determine equality

```
bool SortedListsIter::iterator::operator==(iterator other) 
{ return std::is_permutation(m_items.begin(), m_items.end(), other.m_items.begin(), other.m_items.end()); }
```

C++11 alternative (4 iterator version that checks distance isn't available):

```
bool SortedListsIter::iterator::operator==(iterator other) 
{ return (std::distance(m_items.begin(), m_items.end()) == std::distance(other.m_items.begin(), other.m_items.end())) 
      && std::is_permutation(m_items.begin(), m_items.end(), other.m_items.begin()); }
```

Item equality is simple:

```
bool SortedListIterItem::operator==(SortedListIterItem other) 
{ return (it_beg == other.it_beg) && (it_end == other.it_end); }
```